# Embed External JS from none secure site when using secure server

Tags: javascript, php, ssl

This might seem like a strange question, but I have a secure website which is trying to access an external Javascript file.

The only problem is that the file is coming from a none secure location, going to it through https:// brings up a warning saying it's insecure which means it won't work when using...

```
<script src="//site.com/script.js"></script>
```

Has anyone got any suggestions on how I can embed the script so it works? Maybe some magic PHP which could help?

I have tried to do a little searching around, but I have had 0 results so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either you write a proxy on your server, ask the third party to add ssl, host the file yourself, or you deal with the mixed content warnings?

Comment: I would host it myself, but it just echoes out the last couple of week's updates and changes dynamically their end. I'll go with contacting them to add SSL to the domain. It's Mailchimp, so they should be okay doing it.